# Third Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, set-partitions

\$\left\{ n \atop k \right\}\$ or \$S(n, k)\$ is a way of referring to the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), the number of ways to partition a set of \$n\$ items into \$k\$ non-empty subsets. For example, to partition \$\{1,2,3,4\}\$ into \$2\$ non-empty subsets, we have

$$\begin{matrix}
\{\{1\},\{2,3,4\}\} & \{\{2\},\{1,3,4\}\} & \{\{3\},\{1,2,4\}\} & \{\{4\},\{1,2,3\}\} \\
\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\} & \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\} & \{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}
\end{matrix}$$

So \$\left\{ 4 \atop 2 \right\} = S(4,2) = 7\$

Here, we'll only be considering the sequence \$\left\{ n \atop 3 \right\} = S(n, 3)\$, or the ways to partition \$n\$ items into \$3\$ non-empty subsets. This is [A000392](https://oeis.org/A000392). There is also the related sequence which ignores the three leading zeros (so is \$1, 6, 25, 90, 301, ...\$)\${}^*\$.

This is a standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge, where you can choose which of the two related sequences to handle (leading zeros or not). Regardless of which sequence you choose, you should do one of the following:

- Take an integer \$n\$ and output the \$n\$th element of the sequence. This can be \$0\$ or \$1\$ indexed, your choice, and \$n\$'s minimum value will reflect this.
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ elements of the sequence
- Take no input and infinitely output the sequence

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

<sub>\${}^*\$: I'm allowing either sequence, as handling the leading zeros can "fail" for some algorithms that have to compute empty sums</sub>

---

### Test cases

If you ignore the leading zeros, the first 20 elements are

```
1, 6, 25, 90, 301, 966, 3025, 9330, 28501, 86526, 261625, 788970, 2375101, 7141686, 21457825, 64439010, 193448101, 580606446, 1742343625, 5228079450
```

Otherwise, the first 20 elements are

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 25, 90, 301, 966, 3025, 9330, 28501, 86526, 261625, 788970, 2375101, 7141686, 21457825, 64439010, 193448101
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
3Ḋ*)SI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/44Y4uLc1gz/@H2x81rfn/3xQA)

*-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan*

1-indexed sequence without leading zeros. Uses the formula \$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 3^k - 2^k\$.

### Explanation

```
3Ḋ*)SI Main monadic link
   )   For each k in the range [1..n]:
3Ḋ       Remove the first element from the range [1..3]
  *      Raise each to the power of k
    S  Sum (producing [sum(2^k), sum(3^k)])
     I Increments
```

Comment: With some rearrangement you can do this in 6 bytes like so: [`3Ḋ*)SI`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/44Y4uLc1gz/@H2x81rfn/3xQA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Smart idea, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
cþæ*2FS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/58L7Dy7SM3IL/Gxocbn/UtOY/AA)

Now that [xigoi has outgolfed me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231668/66833), I thought I'd share my answer.

This outputs the \$n\$ term of the sequence without leading zeroes.

### How it works

We generate the matrix

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
\binom 1 1 & \binom 2 1 & \cdots & \binom n 1 \\
\binom 1 2 & \binom 2 2 & \cdots & \binom n 2 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
\binom 1 n & \binom 2 n & \cdots & \binom n n
\end{matrix}\right]^2
= \left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & \frac {n(n-1)} 2 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{matrix}\right]^2
= \left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 4 & \cdots & \sum^n_{i=1} i \binom n i \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & \sum^n_{i=1} \binom i 2\binom n i \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$$

We then calculate \$A^2\$ and get the sum of each element, by flattening and taking the total sum. As to *why* this works, I have no idea - I just discovered it after playing around with `þæ*` patterns in Jelly.

```
cþæ*2FS - Main link. Takes n on the left
 þ      - Generate an n x n matrix where each cell (i,j) is:
c       -   iCj (binomial choose)
  æ*2   - Matrix square
     FS - Flatten and sum
```

Comment: Shouldn't the \$\binom 2 i\$ be \$\binom i 2\$?

Comment: @att Yes, it should, typo fixed :)

Comment: By a double counting argument, \$\sum_{i=k}^n \binom{i}{k} \binom{n}{i} = 2^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}\$.  Using the binomial theorem, we can thus conclude that the sum of column \$n\$ is \$3^n - 2^n\$.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
3^(n=scan()+2)/2-2^n+.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZptWmpdckpmfp5GpWa1QnJyYhxDRzFT4bxynkWcLEtbQ1DbS1DfSNYrL09Yz/V/LFZaaXJJflFmVqpGmqWFgZWSg@R8A)

Outputs without the leading zeros, 0-indexed.

Uses formula from [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000392):
$$ a(n) = 9 \cdot 3^n/2 - 4 \cdot 2^n + 1/2 $$

Comment: Nice.  Here's [another 23-byter](https://tio.run/##K/qfZptWmpdckpmfp5GpWa1QnJyYhxDRzFT4n21raAUS1dC0Li7N1TCOy9Y1isvW/F/LFZaaXJJflFmVqpGmqWFoZWSg@R8A) but I can't beat you...

Answer (score 7):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 76 bytes

```
_+0j->2c
b+0j->3d
0j+0_+0b->j
c+j+x->_+j
d+j->x+b+j
j+0c+0d->Out_x+Out_" "!b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f8/XtsgS9fOKJkrCcwwTuEyyNI2AIom6dplcSVrZ2lX6NrFa2dxpWgDpSu0k4BMoIJkbYMUXTv/0pL4Cm0QqaSgpJj0/z8A)

Outputs nonzero values infinitely using the formula \$S(n, 3) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} (3^k - 2^k)\$.

On TIO, this computes up to the 13th element (2375101) before timing out.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:3**n/6-~-2**n/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPylhLK0/fTLdO1wjEAErmFynkKWTmKRQl5qWnahgZaFpxcRYUZeaVKOTpKKRp5Gn@BwA)

Formula from OEIS for \$n>0\$:

$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-2^n+1)$$

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function using [xnor's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231656/43319). 1-indexed.

```apl
2÷⍨1-2∘*-3*-∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@jw9ke9Kwx1jR51zNDSNdbSBdKG/9MetU141Nv3qKv5Ue@aR71bDq03ftQ28VHf1OAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9N4VHvZiMjAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

Port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231656/95792), made/fixed and golfed with hyper-neutrino's and caird coinheringaahing's help.

```
’3*_2*$‘H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0xjrXgjLZVHDTM8/hsZBB1uf9S05j8A)

This doesn't handle leading zeroes.

```
’3*_2*$‘H
’         n-1
 3*       3^(n-1)
   _      From that, subtract
    2*$   2^n
       ‘  Increment that
        H Halve it
```

Comment: Does this correctly output the leading 3x zeros?  I don't know Jelly to 'try it online' with the footer, but the explanation suggests that (counting from zero) the sequence would start: ```1/6```, ```0```, ```0```, ...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It doesn't, I'll mention that in the answer.

Comment: Ah.  My reading of the question was that one needed to output all 3x zeros, or none of them...

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
3ẹ@þṗ¥ẠƇṢ€QL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/44a6dDof3Pdw5/dDSh7sWHGt/uHPRo6Y1gT7/DQ0OtwNZ/wE)

A monadic link that takes \$n\$ as its argument and returns \$a(n)\$. This is longer and less efficient than the answers based on the OEIS formulae, but should work for any value of \$k\$ by varying the first number in the link from 3.
Also, removing the `L` at the end yields the actual sets.

### Explanation

```
3    ¥       | Using 3 as the left argument and n as the right argument:
    ṗ        | - Cartesian power of 3 and n (call this x)
 ẹ@þ         | - Find indices of each of 1 to 3 in each of x
      ẠƇ     | Keep only those lists where all are non-empty
        Ṣ€   | Sort each list
          Q  | Unique
           L | Length
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Surely there is an eight or less out there...</sup>

```
1×Ɱ3$¡FQS
```

A full program that accepts a non-negative integer from STDIN and prints the result using the 0-indexed, no leading zeros option.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w8PRHG9cZqxxa6BYY/P@/CQA)**

#### How?

```
1×Ɱ3$¡FQS - Main Link: no arguments
1         - start with x=1
     ¡    - repeat this (read from STDIN) times:
    $     -   last two links as a monad, x=f(x):
   3      -     three
 ×Ɱ       -     map (across y in [1..3]) with multiplication
      FQS - flatten, deduplicate, sum -> sum of the set of integers encountered
```

Comment: What formula is this based on?

Comment: @xigoi John W. Layman's conjecture on [A000392](https://oeis.org/A000392). Also note the comment about it further down by Fred Daniel Kline.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
#~StirlingS2~3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X7kuuCSzKCczLz3YqM5Y7X9AUWZeiYK@Q7q@Q1BiXnpqtIGOoYFB7P//AA)

Answer (score 5):

## Scala, 132 bytes

```scala
n=>(for{i<-1 to n-1
j<-i+1 to n-1
p<-1.to(n).permutations}yield{Set(p.slice(0,i),p.slice(i,j),p.slice(j,n))map(_.toSet)}).toSet.size
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hVP2ddi2TEifRNLu26aFeg)

Is it short? No. Is it efficient? No. Is it clever? No. Why did I make it? I...don't know. I'll try golfing it later, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 24 bytes

```
|s>-s=3e~s<=2e~sg1-~+/R1
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cs%3E-s%3D3e%7Es%3C%3D2e%7Esg1-%7E%2B%2FR1&inputs=19)

This is a port of [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231656/95671) into Rattle using this formula:

$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{2}(3^{n-1}-2^n+1)$$

## Explanation

```
|                          takes the user's input
 s                         saves the user's input (n) to memory slot 0
  >                        move pointer right
   -                       decrement user's input
    s                      save (n-1) to memory slot 1
     =3                    set the value on top of the stack to 3
       e~                  perform 3^(n-1)
         s                 save in memory slot 1
          <                move pointer left
           =2              set the value on top of the stack to 2
             e~            perform 2^(n)
               s           save in memory slot 0
                g1         get value from slot 1
                  -~       subtract value in slot 0
                    +      increment
                     /     divide by 2
                      R1   reformat as int (which is printed implicitly)
```

Comment: Can you not remove the `R1`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing unfortunately it's needed for n = 0, it can be removed otherwise (I'm currently trying to golf it more to not need that)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 34 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n<3?0:5*f(n-1)-6*f(n-2)+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBboMwDL3zFRZSJaBBI4SEMMp2mPYVKweUhg5tSyuotGoVvz5mt7TbosSJ37Md@5l4a8w0tYELT65yK/GY3MsI3ZiHsTo/0nDJy3Hq3AE@ms4FoXfyABcB9ri35mA3LzVUcEoYXDZnoBikkkGBnkjQL5Si1xkTAtFUS8K1kinFKq6Iy7UucmJFLjnxOc@40hTBM5lrilFZJoqE0z@FyDKNcWN5bsm8Nn2E1po322NPQF356@Nzuj4WT3ikz@CvL/w5s931ENBEDlOSEq8VDN2X3bXBdcbwbgaiG1LCculCuOhx1WTACqRn@Q@1iN7UcvUvue@RbgN/sYH4AdAuhrXDNh2Dgd1msVU11HPJ0Runb9O@N9thij9/AA)

Inputs \$0\$-based  \$n\$.
Returns \$S(n,3)\$.
Uses the formula: \$a(n) = 5\cdot a(n-1) - 6\cdot a(n-2) + 1\$, for \$n > 2\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.extras`, 18 bytes

```
[ 3 + 3 stirling ]
```

Ignoring leading zeroes. Zero-indexed. `stirling` is bugged in the build TIO uses. It was fixed about three years ago, so here's a picture of running it in the listener with a more recent build.

[image]

Comment: now this is a mathematica level threat

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 10 bytes

```
+0?+1+_0+0__!2?-+_{0
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIrXG4wPysxK18wKzBcbl9cbl8hMj8tK197MCIsIlsyXSIsMF0)

1-indexed sequence without leading zeros. Uses the formula \$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^k - 2^k\$.

### Explanation

```
+ sum
0       range
?           n
+         +
1           1
+     copy-last
_
0           0
+         +
0           0
_   map
_
!           3
2         ^
?           k
-     -
+       2^
_           [k,n]
{         index
0           0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
-/3 2⊥¨∘⊂1,⍴∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1ffWMHoUdfSQysedcx41NVkqPOodwuQafg/7VHbhEe9fY/6pnr6P@pqPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/Tzu0QuFR72YjAwA)

A function implementing the sum formula using base conversion:

$$
a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \left( 3^k-2^k \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n 3^k - \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = (\underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{n+1})_3 - (\underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{n+1})_2
$$

```apl
           ⍴∘1   ⍝ a vector of n 1's
         1,      ⍝ prepend an additional 1
        ⊂        ⍝ enclose in a length 1 list
  3 2⊥¨          ⍝ for each of 2 and 3 decode the vector from that base
-/               ⍝ reduce the result by subtraction
```

If we use a full program instead of a function, this and a port of caird's Jelly answer are 13 bytes:

[`-/3 2⊥¨⊂1,⎕⍴1`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@uvrGC0aOupYdWPOpqMtR51Df1Ue8WQ5Dc/zQuEwA) and [`+/∊+.×⍨∘.!⍨⍳⎕`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@2/qOOLm29w9Mf9a541DFDTxFE925@1DcVJP8/jcsEAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Same approach as my APL answer.

```
$>и32SβÆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxe7CDmOj4HObDrf9/28MAA)

```python
$          # push 1 and input n
 >         # increment n
  и        # a list of n+1 1's
   32S     # push list [3, 2]
      β    # for each of those numbers, convert the list of 1's from that base
       Æ   # reduce by subtraction
```

The first three bytes could be `>Å1` instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4HNu63@7w62GxkbB5zYdbvv/3xgA)

A few alternatives from 8 to 11 bytes:

```
o3I<mα>;       port of xnor's answer          Try it online!
32SILδmOÆ      the sum formula                Try it online!
o<·3ILmOα      sum(3^k, k=1..n)-(2^n-1)*2     Try it online!
Î>FNo-3Nm+     sum using a for loop           Try it online!
LDδcDøδ*˜O     port of caird's answer         Try it online!
3Å0λ5*₂6*->    a(n)=5*a(n-1)-6*a(n-2)+1       Try it online! (infinite sequence)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 16 bytes

```
L,Rd3€^¦+$2€^¦+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJyjF@FHTmrhDy7RVjKCM@P///5v@yy8oyczPK/6vmwkA)

Frick you caird for making such a painful esolang (:p). Port of everyone's favourite Jelly answer by xigoi.

### Explained

```
L,Rd3€^¦+$2€^¦+_
L,               # make a lambda that:
  Rd             #   pushes the range [1, input] twice and
    3€^          #   raises 3 to the power of each item,
       ¦+        #   summing that list (can't use s to sum here because frick you caird)
         $2€^¦+  #   do the same with 2
               _ #   subtract the two items. The i flag automatically runs the lambda and implicitly outputs the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sr`, 6 bytes

```
ƛ23fe¯
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=sr&code=%C6%9B23fe%C2%AF&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

A port of xigoi's Jelly answer

### Explained

````
ƛ23fe¯
ƛ      # over the range [1, input] (call each item n) 

 23f   #   the list [2, 3]
    e  #   ^ ** n
     ¯ #   deltas of ^
       # the s flag auto-sums the result
```
````

Comment: Vyxal really likes to abuse our “CL flags = different language” rules :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩΣＥ⊕Ｎ⁻Ｘ³ιＸ²ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDMy@5KDU3Na8kNQXILigt8SvNTUot0tDU1FHwzcwrLdYIyC8H8o11FDKBQhCOEYgDBtb//xsZ/NctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses @xigoi's Risky formulation of @Nitrodon's formula. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ           Input integer
   ⊕            Incremented
  Ｅ             Map over implicit range
      Ｘ³ι       Power of 3
     ⁻          Subtract
         Ｘ²ι    Power of 2
 Σ              Sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

I tried porting a couple of the other formulae too but they weighed in at 14 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
s n=div(3^n-3*2^n+3)6
```

$$\left\{n\atop3\right\}=\frac{3^n-3!\left\{n\atop2\right\}-3\left\{n\atop1\right\}}{3!}=\frac{3^n-3!\frac{2^n-2}{2!}-3}{3!}=\frac{3^n-3(2^n-2)-3}{3!}=\frac{3^n-3\cdot2^n+6-3}{6}=\frac{3^n-3\cdot2^n+3}6$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1ghzzYls0zDOC5P11jLKC5P21jT7H9uYmaebUFRZl6JSrGNil20gZ6ekXHsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 17 bytes

```
n->(2^n-3^n\3)\-2
```

With leading zeros.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWG_N07TSM4vJ0jePyYow1Y3SNIOI3VdLyizTyFGwVDHQUjIC4oCgzrwQooKSgawck0jTyNDU1IWoXLIDQAA)

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 18 bytes

```
n->stirling(n,3,2)
```

With leading zeros.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWm_J07YpLMotyMvPSNfJ0jHWMNCESN1XS8os08hRsFQx0FIyAuKAoM68EKKCkoGsHJNI08jQ1oWoXLIDQAA)

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 14 bytes

```
n->-3^n\-2-2^n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboW6_J07XSN4_JidI10jeLyIII3VdLyizTyFGwVDHQUjIC4oCgzrwQooKSgawck0jTyNDU1IWoXLIDQAA)

This gives the sequence `0, 0, 1, 6, 25, 90, 301, 966, ...`. I'm not sure if this is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
3p°U -2pU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=M3CwVSAtMnBV&input=OA)

```
3p°U -2pU     :Implicit map of each U in [0,input)
3p            :3 raised to the power of
  °U          :  U, prefix incremented
     -        :Subtract
      2pU     :2 raised to the power of U
              :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 13 bytes

```
Đ1⇹«⇹⁻3⇹^⇹-⁺₂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yATDR@07D60GEo8adxsDqTgg1n3UuOtRU9P//yYA)

Port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231656/95792)